# Persist Redis data in Oracle database instead of Disk

Tags: database, oracle, redis, persistence

I am trying to evaluate Redis as a distributed cache for my application. I know that redis supports persistence and we can use RDB or AOF options for persisting data to disk. However is there a possibility to persist data in Oracle database instead of a Disk ?

I don't see any OOTB solution for this. Redissson client library seems to provide some API for loading and storing data. But I am not sure if there is something else which is available.

Shashidhar

Comment: Further analysis - It seems that Oracle Coherence provides support for persisting to any data store,  it can be a Oracle NoSQL or Oracle Relational Database. However I am not sure if such support is there in Redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did some further analysis and it seems that there is OOTB support for persisting cache data in any of the database. We can use Redisson as Java client library and then implement [MapWriter](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.redisson/redisson/3.10.3/org/redisson/api/map/MapWriter.html) and [MapLoader](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.redisson/redisson/3.6.0/org/redisson/api/map/MapLoader.html) for wrtiting and reading data from the Database.

Thanks
Shashidhar